# 500 Internal Server Error trying to start session with shopify python api

Tags: python, api, shopify

I'm following the tutorial on https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api but at step 4 I always get an "500 Internal Server Error".

I'm not sure whether I do follow the steps correctly.

After step 3 I visit the URL in `permission_url` in my browser click "Install" and then copy the data from the URL I get redirected to into a python `dict` called `params`.

On executing step 4 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/session.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.token = self.request_token(params['code'])
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/session.py", line 90, in request_token
    response = connection.post(access_token_path, ShopifyResource.headers)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 313, in post
    return self._open('POST', path, headers=headers, data=data)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 18, in _open
    self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 258, in _open
    response = Response.from_httpresponse(self._handle_error(err))
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 367, in _handle_error
    raise ServerError(err)
ServerError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Could you provide me with the application id.  It is the number in the url when you go to the app from the partners dashboard.  E.g. `https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients/124374` means my application id is 124374.

Comment: So you mean that I can not just go to myshopnamemyshopify.com/admin/api click "Generate new application" an use the data provided there?
Because I don't have a partners account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a private application you do not need to go through the authorization steps to get a token.  The token is simply private applications password.  So activating a session just requires doing:

```
session = shopify.Session(SHOP_URL)
session.token = PRIVATE_APPLICATION_PASSWORD
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)
```